# Pronunciation of borrowed/foreign terms in French

Tags: prononciation

I have encountered on many occasions French pronouncing foreign words according to French reading rules, rather than the way the word is pronounced in the original language. I didn't bother to collect the examples, and the only one that I can readily think of is [*Kärcher*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4rcher) (initially I mistakenly took it for something like English *car-share*, since you often encounter this device when washing a car.)

What is the traditional way of pronouncing foreign words in French: close to spelling or close to the original? What is the recommendation of the [Académie Française](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acad%C3%A9mie_Fran%C3%A7aise) in this regard?

Comment: the Académie's recommendation isn't relevant. They are no experts.

Answer (score 3):

There's no general rule, usage makes the rule. The pronunciation of foreign words varies a lot, depending on language of origin, popularity, field, date of borrowing, among other things.

English words borrowed a long time ago usually have a different pronunciation from ones borrowed more recently, as people are more familiar with English pronunciation in general.

Many words also have multiple coexisting pronunciations. For example, Uber can be pronounced /ybɛʁ/, /ybœʁ/, /œbœʁ/ and more rarely /ubœʁ/.

Generally, I'd say it's a balance between somewhat respecting the pronunciation in the origin language (or what we think it is) and ease of use. If it's a pain to say "correctly" people will tend to use an easier pronunciation.

Sometimes a word is introduced arbitrarily introduced with one pronunciation, from an ad or a movie, and there's no debate or hesitation, even if it's not "accurate".

Usually, there's more hesitation when a word is introduced only in written form, nowadays mostly from the internet. Like Twitter's "threads" (/tʁɛd/ or /sʁɛd/) or Instagram's "reels" (/ʁe.ɛl/ or /ʁil/).

Comment: The use of "threads" in French is older than Twitter, and I hear "frèd" quite a lot (more than "trèd").

Comment: You will also find regional differences for the same word. This is audible when a Québécois and a Français use a word which comes from the English language. In Québec, where we hear more English, the pronunciation is usually more English-like.